# PHP notice when using variable in $_SESSION array to retrieve userdata

Tags: php, session, undefined, offset, notice

I'm getting this php notice on this code:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1

What I expect is the function to return the mail of the user, example: test@mail.com in this example:

```
$userId = 1;    
getUserById($userId, 'mail');

    function getUserById($id, $string = '') {
        return getUser($string, $id);
    }
    function getUser($id = '', $string = '') {
        if(isLoggedIn() || $id != '') {     //If user is logged in or if id is sent
            if($string == '') {
                return $_SESSION['loggedIn']['fName']   .   ' ' .   $_SESSION['loggedIn']['lName'];     //Return logged in users first name and lastname as a string
            }
            else {
                return $_SESSION['loggedIn'][$string];      //Return logged in users email as a string
            }
        }
        else {      //If user is not logged in return false
            return false;
        }
    }
```

If I were to call it like:

```
getUserById($userId, 'phoneNumber');
```

the function would return the users phone number.

I've got no idea why Im recieving this notice, any help how to fix it is appreciated! :)

Comment: Have you started the session?

Answer (score 3):

The order of the params is wrong  when you call `getUser`. First needs to be the `$id` and then the `$string`.

This is how it should be:

```
function getUserById($id, $string = '') {
    return getUser($id, $string);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have no idea how I coulve missed something that simple. I literally searched for hours :S

Answer (score 1):

You have inverted the params in `getUser`.
It should be:

```
return getUser( $id, $string);
```

Comment: Thank you! Cant believe I missed something so simple, I literally searched for hours :S